# Reduce height of image inside div as viewport height decreases?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails

In my Rails app I have modals that pop up sometimes containing photos. These photos have default dimensions of 600 x 600. What I need to do is reduce the height of the modal (div) and image when the viewport height decreases so the modal extend beyond the fold of the page.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="photo_preview">
    <div id="inner-preview-container">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" id="remove"></span>
        <%= image_tag Product.find(@product.id).photo.url(:large).sub('http://s3.amazonaws.com/anymarket/','http://anymarket.s3.amazonaws.com/') %>
        <div id="info-preview-container">
            <h4><a href="/products/<%= @product.id %>"><%= @product.name %></a></h4>
            <p>By <%= User.find(@product.user_id).first_name %> <%= User.find(@product.user_id).last_name %></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#photo_preview {
  @extend #send_question_wrapper;
  z-index:1000;
  width:600px;
  background-color:white;
  border:1px solid #bbb;
  border-radius:3px;
  padding:5px;
  top:50px !important;
  img{
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
  }
  #remove {
    float:right;
    color:#bbb;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    cursor:pointer;
  }
}
```

What do I need to do to accomplish what I want to do? I've tried setting the img height to auto but it didn't work.

Comment: use height percentages?

Answer (score 0):

assuming your modal's ID is photo_preview (it's not clear), just do this:

```
#photo_preview, #photo_preview img{width: 100%; max-width:600px;}
```

which is the same as

```
#photo_preview, #photo_preview img{height: 100%; max-height:600px;}
```

since your images are all the same square size. You can use any of them, but width IN GENERAL acts better in responsive sizes